# Making GUI update information from double array?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

I have a cardfield that is a double array and a GUI for it, with a JButton/JTextArea for each cardfield. I'm having trouble making the GUI update with card information when the double array does.

I have tried repaint() and revalidate() but those didn't work. I'm pretty sure that's because it just updates the GUI itself, but I want it to be connected to the double array. I always tried using a thread, and I'm pretty sure that's the answer, I'm just having trouble implementing it.

How would I make a thread run continuously in the background that takes information from each element in the double array and sends it to the appropriate JTextArea/JButton? Basically when a player uses placeCard, I want the GUI to update the information as well, not only the double array field. I have researched threads a bit before asking this, but in the documentation the examples used makes a whole class that is ran by a thread, but I would just want to have one method ran in the background for updating this.

Comment: Please post your code. This problem is to broad otherwise.

Comment: I realize that, it's not really a problem with my code just how would I implement this. I know you guys don't like general questions but I did spend some time trying to find a way to do this and I was stuck. 
I can post my code if you really want it, but I don't see how it would change anything. 

Basically: double array with each element being a card field/slot. 
when a person places onto the double array, I want the GUI to update  the corresponding JTextArea.

Comment: Actually I suspect it is a problem with code, not concurrency. 

Remember that all built in components have data represented in a model, and you must update this model as well. So basically you need to update this model everytime you touch the double array.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. Currently reading the documentation MadProgrammer posted as an answer. I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when dealing with concurrency in Swing. Swing is not thread safe. There is a golden rule when dealing with Swing, that is, you are expected to only update UI components from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and attention to the section on [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)